# Remove vs New Instance

Tags: .net, stringbuilder

I'm wondering what a better practice is in general .NET programming with class instances that contain a Remove method.

The question is:
if I have a StringBuilder sb with some data, is it smarter to use the .Remove(0, sb.Length) or to create a new instance and leave the old to the GC to collect. There are quite a few factors that I am aware of so I would like to know your opinions on this one.

Thanks,

Sanjin

Comment: You'll get both answers, you just didn't give enough details.  Like the .NET version, big changes in .NET 4.0 for StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, create a new one.

The .NET memory system is geared toward creating and de-allocating lots of small, short-lived objects quickly. StringBuilder.Remove() is likely to be slower.

For very large data (over 80kB) the rules change a little, depending on lots of factors.

Comment: Especially since `Remove` might not recognize(I didn't look into the source) that you're removing the whole buffer and thus end up in an unoptimized codepath designed for removes from the middle of the string. And of course Remove is harder to read

Comment: I think that this is the info I needed :) a data size is a perfect reference ^_^ thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go for creating a new instance until a profiler has shown that this is the most critical part of your application.

This micro optimization kind of reuse just confuses any readers about the intent of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.Remove(0, sb.Length)` use `.Clear()` instead. It's easier to read and if Remove hasn't been optimized for this special use-case `Clear` will be faster too.
Or just allocate a new StringBuilder. The StringBuilder itself it lightweight, so I don't think using a new one will be expensive.
I usually wouldn't distinguish `Clear()` and allocating a new StringBuilder based on performance benefits of one, but on which creates the better readable code. And that depends on your use-case. Don't micro optimize unless you're profiler has shown that it's necessary.
In my experience you allocate a new StringBuilder at the beginning of some method and only call `ToString` when producing the return-value of the function. In that case it's stupid to complicate the function interface just to reuse a StringBuilder.

And I think when you call `ToString()` the StringBuilder gives out it's internal, so the internal buffer becomes immutable and StringBuilder needs to allocate a new on the next change one anyways.

One micro-optimization that can be useful is passing in a capacity to the constructor of a StringBuilder, if you know exactly(or at least a lower bound on) how long the result will be. Then it doesn't have to grow the array in multiple steps. For example if you know that the output will be at least 10000 characters you can init the builder to a capacity of 10000.

Comment: OK, Clear is better than Remove but should the OP use either?

Comment: That mainly depends on which produces the better readable code.

Comment: The thing is that there is no .Clear() is SB ... probably for a good reason so I'll go for now with a new instance, thanks ppl.

Comment: It exists in .net 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.clear.aspx "Clear is a convenience method that is equivalent to setting the Length property of the current instance to 0 (zero)."